# Set of continuous functions so that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $n$ such that $f_n(x)$ rational

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be continuous function. Suppose that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is some $n$ such that $f_n(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that for every $c < d$ in $\mathbb{R}$, one can find some numbers $a < b$ in the interval $(c,d)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n$ is constant on $(a,b)$.

---

My intuition for this question is that I would want to use something like the intermediate value theorem (a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133434/prove-that-if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbq-is-continuous-then-f-is-constant) does that)? But I'm not sure how everything goes together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix $[c,d]$ enumerate rationals, say by $q_m$. Now, for any $n$ and any $m$ the set $A_{n.m} = f_{n}^{-1}(q_m)\cap [c,d]$ is closed (because functions are continuous).
From Baire's category theorem and assumptions on the functions $[c,d]= \cup{A_{n,m}}$
so one of $A_{n,m}$ has to have non empty interior, hence it contains sub-interval $[a,b]$.